# How to calculate a distance between two points along a path?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3, turfjs

I'm using openlayers3 and I have the encoded geometry. I can get the coordinates (lat,lng) for all points in the path (around 500 points per path). Given a random point inside the path, how do I calculate the distance between the beginning of the path up to that point?

I've taken a look at turfjs and it looks very promising, but the solution I pictured using it wouldn't be very nice. Taking a random point (p1), I could discover the point (p2) of the path that is closest to p1, then generate a new polygon and calculate its total distance. It may have performance issues, although the search would be O(log n) and the new polygon O(n).

EDIT: the random point is not necessarily inside the path, it's a GPS coordinate and there's a margin for error.

EDIT 2: estimation on the number of points was off, each path has about 500 points, not 5k

Does anyone know of a better approach? I'm not very experienced with either openlayers3 nor turfjs.

Comment: 5k points per path sounds pretty dense, you can interpret this as a polyline. I'd create (and cache) an Array that holds the sum of distances from the start to each point. Therefore you can get the distance between two of your points by 2 Array-lookups + a subtraction.

Comment: You can loop the points of the path, calculating distances of individual paths, storing the last point and check in each iteration if desired point is between the last point and the actual point. If the condition is true then use this random point as actual point and stop calculating.

Comment: @Thomas, this random point is not one of the coordinates, so it's not just a simple lookup, I have to find the closest coordinate to the random point.

Comment: @jose-hermosilla-rodrigo the point is not necessarily inside the path, the random point is a GPS coordinate, so there could be some positioning error. Anyway, your answer is the more complete so far, if no better options emerge put it on an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: use the formula using the cross product to get the distance. You will just need 2 points of the line, and the point you want to calculate the distance with.

Comment: Let me some time and i'll elaborate complete answer.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant, not sure I got your idea. What you described would give me only the distance of the random point from a line between two points, but that's just a small part of the path.

Comment: @lalkmim, true, but you don't have to compute the distance along the path anymore. And you already know the distance to the closestPoint, because you had to compute it to determine wich point is the closest. So your actual distance-computation boils down to basic arithmetic operations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you mentioned you're using OpenLayers 3, I've done an example using `OpenLayers 3`, the idea is:

1. Get `Closest Point across the LineString` given a coordinate
2. Iterate over LineString points calculating the distance of each individual paths and see if our closest point intersects the individual path.

```js
/* Let's Generate a Random LineString */

var length = 5000;

var minLongitude = Math.random()*-180 + 180;

var minLatitude = Math.random()*-90 + 90;

var wgs84Sphere = new ol.Sphere(6378137);

var lastPoint = [minLongitude, minLatitude]

var points = Array.from({ length })
.map( _ =>{
  var newPoint =  [
    Math.random() * (Math.random() > 0.8 ? -.005 : .005) + lastPoint[0]
    , Math.random() * (Math.random() > 0.2 ? -.005 : .005) + lastPoint[1]
  ]
  lastPoint = newPoint;
  return newPoint;
})

var distanceTotal = points
.reduce((dis, p, i)=>{
  if(points[i + 1])
    dis += wgs84Sphere.haversineDistance(p, points[i + 1] )
    return dis;          
}, 0);

console.log(distanceTotal)

var extent = new ol.extent.boundingExtent(points)

//console.log(points)

var lineString = new ol.Feature({
  geometry : new ol.geom.LineString(points)
});

var source = new ol.source.Vector();

var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({ source });

source.addFeature(lineString);


var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  controls: ol.control.defaults({
    attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
      collapsible: false
    })
  }),
  view: new ol.View({
    projection : 'EPSG:4326',
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  })
});

map.addLayer(layer)
map.getView().fit(extent, map.getSize())

var auxLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({ source : new ol.source.Vector() })

var styleAux = new ol.style.Style({
  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
    color: 'green',
    width: 2
  })
});

var styleAuxLine = new ol.style.Style({
  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
    color: 'green',
    width: 0.5
  })
});

var styleAuxPoint = new ol.style.Style({
  image : new ol.style.Circle({
    radius: 5,
    fill: null,
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: 'black', width: 2})
  })
});

var styleAuxSourcePoint = new ol.style.Style({
  image : new ol.style.Circle({
    radius: 3,
    fill: null,
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: '#00bbff', width: 0.5})
  })
});

auxLayer.setStyle(function(f, r){
  var type = f.getGeometry().getType();
  if(type === 'LineString') return styleAux;
  return styleAuxPoint;
})

map.addLayer(auxLayer);

map.on('pointermove', function(e){
  if(e.dragging) return;
  var coord = e.coordinate;
  var distance = 0;

  var pointsGeometry = [];

  var sourcePointFeature = new ol.Feature({
    geometry : new ol.geom.Point(coord)
  });

  var closestPoint = lineString.getGeometry().getClosestPoint(coord);                
  var lineDiffFeature = new ol.Feature({
    geometry : new ol.geom.LineString([
      coord, closestPoint
    ])
  });
  for(let i = 0; i< points.length - 1; i++){
    var p = points[i]
    var next = points[i + 1];
    var subLineStringGeom = new ol.geom.LineString([ p, next ]);

    pointsGeometry.push(p);

    var e = 1e-10;
    var extent = [ closestPoint[0] - e, closestPoint[1] - e
                  , closestPoint[0] + e, closestPoint[1] + e
                 ]

    if(subLineStringGeom.intersectsExtent(extent)){
      //console.log(i);
      pointsGeometry.push(closestPoint);
      distance += wgs84Sphere.haversineDistance(p, closestPoint);
      break;
    }
    distance += wgs84Sphere.haversineDistance(p, next);
  }
  console.log(closestPoint)
  var cpGeometry = new ol.geom.Point(closestPoint);
  var cpFeature = new ol.Feature({ geometry : cpGeometry });

  var geometry = new ol.geom.LineString(pointsGeometry);
  var newFeature = new ol.Feature({ geometry });

  auxLayer.getSource().clear();
  auxLayer.getSource().refresh();

  auxLayer.getSource().addFeature(lineDiffFeature);
  auxLayer.getSource().addFeature(newFeature);
  auxLayer.getSource().addFeature(sourcePointFeature);
  auxLayer.getSource().addFeature(cpFeature);
  sourcePointFeature.setStyle(styleAuxSourcePoint);
  lineDiffFeature.setStyle(styleAuxLine);
  //console.log(geometry.getLength())
  console.log(distance);

})
```

```css
html, body, #map {
  width : 100%;
  height : 100%;
  padding : 0px;
  margin : 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/build/ol.js"></script>
<link href="https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="map" class="map" tabindex="0"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was extremely helpful.